# How to create the Parent build.gradle(having common configuration) and call it from module build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi module project which I am writing in gradle.I want to run the test like findbugs,pmd,jococo and checkstyle and some confgiuration which is same for all so I want to create the parent gradle and module build.gradle script.I don't know how to call the parent build.gradle from module gradle script.Can someone give me an example how could I achieve this so that I don't need to write the same thing in each every module.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'maven'

//-- set the group for publishing
group = 'com.trxxxx.abcd'

/**
 * Initializing GAVC settings
 */
def buildProperties = new Properties()
file("version.properties").withInputStream { 
    stream -> buildProperties.load(stream) 
} 
//add the jenkins build version to the version
def env = System.getenv()
if (env["BUILD_NUMBER"]) buildProperties.abcdBuildVersion += "_${env["BUILD_NUMBER"]}"
version = buildProperties.abcdBuildVersion
println "${version}"

//name is set in the settings.gradle file
group = "com.ngfh.abcd"
version = buildProperties.abcdBuildVersion
println "Building ${project.group}:${project.name}:${project.version}"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
jar {
   manifest {
       attributes 'Implementation-Title': "${project.name}",
                   'Implementation-Version': "${project.version}",
                   'Implementation-Vendor-Id': "${project.group}"
                  }
}                
  repositories {

    maven {
      url "http://cmxxxxt.tsh.thon.com:80/ncds/cache"
    }
  }

dependencies {
    compile ([
    "com.eaio.uuid:uuid:3.2",
    "org.springframework:spring-context:2.5.6",
    "org.springframework:spring-beans:1.2.6" ,
    "org.springframework:spring-core:1.2.3",
    "org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.6.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.7.RELEASE",
    "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.1.3",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.3",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.3",
    "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6",
    "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0",
    "junit:junit:4.+"
      ])
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}
test {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    executionData = fileTree(dir: 'build/jacoco', include: '**/*.exec')

    reports {
        xml{
            enabled true
            //Following value is a file
            destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/xml/jacoco.xml"
        }
        csv.enabled false
     html{
       enabled true
       //Following value is a folder
       destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/html"
     }
    }
}

findbugs {
        ignoreFailures = true
       //sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
   }

pmd { 
         ruleSets = ["java-basic", "java-braces", "java-design"] 
         ignoreFailures = true
         //sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
   }

checkstyle {
      configFile = new File(rootDir, "config/checkstyle.xml")
      ignoreFailures = true
      //sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
   }

// adding test report to taskGraph
build.dependsOn jacocoTestReport

def pomFile = file("${buildDir}/libs/${archivesBaseName.toLowerCase()}-${version}.pom")
task newPom << {
  pom {
      project {
          groupId project.group
          artifactId project.name
          version project.version
          description = "Configuration Management Gradle Plugin"
      }
  }.writeTo(pomFile)
}
// adding pom generation to taskGraph
build.dependsOn newPom

//disabling the install task since we're not using maven for real
install.enabled = false

//for publishing to artifactory via jenkins
if(project.hasProperty('artifactoryPublish')) {
  artifactoryPublish {
    mavenDescriptor pomFile
  }
}

// ------ Publish the jar file to artifactory ------
artifacts {
  jar
  newPom
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have configuration that is common to all projects of your multi project build then you can simply place it in an `allprojects { }` block.

```
allprojects {
    // place config that should be included in every project
}
```

Comment: I am spliting my projects in module so each module is having there own gradle script.But I want to create a Parent gradle script which is having the  configuration related to test which will apply to all modules and keep it into the gradle init.d location so when anyone run any grald emodule script from jenkins it will run the test on that module also.

Comment: You could do exactly what I posted above in an initialization script.